# Параметры шаблона функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Вот такой вот простой шаблон функции, который возвращает удвоенное значение. Но в параметры я могу писать только числа? (`int`, `double`...) Но только числа? Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы в параметры можно было бы записать еще и строку допустим и на выходе получать что-то типа stringstring или это из области фантастики? Компилятор слово `data` воспринимает как числа разных типов, или еще может воспринимать как тип данных `string` например?

```
template< class TYPE >
void PrintTwice(TYPE data)
{
    cout << "Double meaning: " << data * 2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `data * 2` написать `data + data`, передайте шаблонной функции объект типа `string` и посмотрите на вывод программы :)

Comment: @wololo говорит что бинарный оператор + не подходит для типов данных типа char. значит шаблоны функций имеют ограничения ...

Comment: [Пример](https://ideone.com/aaa461)

Comment: @wololo супер! вышлооо!! спасибоо!!!

Comment: " значит шаблоны функций имеют ограничения" — если очень коротко, то в данном конкретном случае имеет место не ограничение шаблонов, а то обстоятельство, что нельзя умножать объекты типа `string` на целые числа.

Comment: @wololo да, вы абсолютно правы:))) спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вашу шаблонную функцию можно передавать не только числа, а абсолютно все, для чего выражение `data * 2` имеет какой-то смысл и возвращает результат, который можно вывести через `<<`.

Например, если мы перегрузим бинарный `*` для `std::string` вот так

```
std::string operator *(std::string lhs, unsigned rhs)
{
  std::string str;
  for (; rhs > 0; --rhs)
    str += lhs;
  return str;
}
```

то ваш шаблон будет делать именно то, что вы хотите, то есть выводить удвоенную строку

```
PrintTwice(std::string("test"));
```

В этом как раз и заключается вся суть шаблонов: они реализуют концепцию duck typing ("утиной типизации"). Им глубоко все равно, что за типы вы в них используете и связаны ли эти типы как-то между собой. Все, что им надо - это чтобы после подстановки этих типов в шаблонный код этот код получался формально правильным.

---

С этой точки зрения этот вопрос перекликается с вашим же (ныне удаленным) вопросом о том, зачем перегружать оператор `<<` для пользовательского типа `Date`, если можно обойтись без этого.

На самом деле, перегрузив оператор вывода `<<` для своего типа `Date` вы тем самым сделали его совместимым с уже существующими средствами стандартной библиотеки. Например, точно так же как мы можем "в одну строку", пользуясь стандартным алгоритмом `std::copy`, вывести на выход целый массив объектов `std::string`

```
std::string mama[] = ( "Mama", "myla", "ramu" };
std::copy(std::begin(mama), std::end(mama), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

мы сможем вывести на выход и массив ваших объектов `Date`

```
Date date[] = { ... };
std::copy(std::begin(date), std::end(date), std::ostream_iterator<Date>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

но только если для вашего `Date` определен оператор `<<`.

---

В данном же случае, определив оператор `*` для `std::string`, мы сделали `std::string` совместимым с вашей функцией `PrintTwice`.

Однако такой подход - с переопределением оператора `*` для `std::string` - следует использовать только в том случае, если такое переопределение является естественным и логичным расширением функциональности `std::string`. В данном случае ответ на этот вопрос неоднозначен (скорее нет, чем да). Я привел его лишь в качестве примера.

И если вы считаете такое поведение оператора `*` для `std::string` ненатуральным, то более правильным способом приспосабливания функции `PrintTwice` к работе с `std::string` будет явная специализация (как в ответе @Boris) или, лучше, обычная перегрузка функции

```
void PrintTwice(const std::string &data)
{
  std::cout << "Double meaning: " << data << data << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В случае если для передаваемого типа перегружен оператор умножения, это должно работать, в противном случае будет вызвана ошибка компиляции.

Вы можете написать специализацию шаблона для строки:

```
template<>
void PrintTwice(std::string data)
{
    std::cout << "Double meaning: " << data + data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: А еще проще - убрать `template<>` и не мучиться :) - перегрузка для функций ничуть не хуже специализации.