# Перегрузка операторов - уточнение

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Почему вот [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx) называется перегрузкой оператора? `cout` разве не выводит пользовательские типы БЕЗ перегрузки?

```
// overload_date.cpp  
// compile with: /EHsc  
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

class Date  
{  
    int mo, da, yr;  
public:  
    Date(int m, int d, int y)  
    {  
        mo = m; da = d; yr = y;  
    }  
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt);  
};  

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)  
{  
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;  
    return os;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);  
    cout << dt;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что, в стандартном С++ есть оператор

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
```

т.е. для вывода `Date`?

Нет, его нет. Он создается программистом для своего пользовательского типа.

Если я определю, например, функцию

```
myClass sqrt(myClass& m);
```

которая будет выполнять какие-то свои действия - вы же не будете говорить - разве `sqrt` не считает квадратный корень без перегрузки?

Но, кстати, `cout` выводит пользовательские типы, вообще говоря, с использованием перегрузки.

На всякий случай напомню, что такое перегрузка...

Под перегрузкой функции понимается, определение нескольких функций (две или больше) с одинаковым именем, но различными параметрами. Наборы параметров перегруженных функций могут отличаться порядком следования, количеством, типом.

Comment: но разве нельзя сделать так cout << mo << da << yr << endl; ? в чем смысл данной перегрузки?

Comment: это закрытые данные класса - компилятор не может знать что такое mo  или da.  Просто  вы сами их обьявили закрытыми

Comment: Нельзя, потому что эти данные закрыты. Если сделаете открытыми - можете писать `cout << dt.mo << dt.da << dt.yr` - это, конечно же, короче и понятнее, чем написать `cout << dt`... :)

Comment: @Harry а в этой перегрузке что бы получить доступ мы обьявляем дружественную функцию) стит ли писать десятки строчек кода?:)

Comment: Зачем десятки? А потом - тогда, знаете, ну какой смысл вообще писать функции? Ведь этот же код можно воткнуть прямо в `main` и не мучиться... Классы там всякие - `Date` какой-то. Зачем? Не проще ли просто три числа везде подставлять, где надо?...

Answer (score 2):

Если поля вашего класса являются доступными извне и вам не лень везде писать руками

```
std::cout << d.mo << d.da << d.yr << std::endl;
```

то с точки зрения удобства и/или сокращения длины кода вам действительно не нужен перегруженный оператор `<<` для вашего `Date`.

Однако ценность такого оператора далеко не сводится к сокращению длины записи. Более того, ценность такого оператора заключается *в первую очередь* именно в том, что он унифицирует интерфейс ввода-вывода вашего класса с принятым в стандартной библиотеке интерфейсом. После переопределения оператора `<<` ваш класс становится совместимым с многими существующими средствами форматированного вывода стандартной библиотеки.

Например, пользуясь стандартным алгоритмом `std::copy` вы сможете вывести на выход массив ваших объектов `Date` через `std::ostream_iterator` вот так

```
Date date[] = { ... };
std::copy(std::begin(date), std::end(date), std::ostream_iterator<Date>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

но только если для вашего `Date` определен оператор `<<`.

(Я вам [уже писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769631/182825) именно об этом.)

Answer (score 1):

```
cout может вывести  данные класса, если они открытые, и для них уже определен оператор вывода. Например:
class Date  
{  
public:
    int mo, da, yr;   
    Date(int m, int d, int y) : mo(m), da(d), yr(y) {} 
};
```

или это тоже самое, что

```
struct Date  
{  
    int mo, da, yr;   
    Date(int m, int d, int y) : mo(m), da(d), yr(y) {} 
};
```

и можно спокойно написать

```
 Date d(1, 1, 2000);
  cout << d.mo << d.da << d.yr;
```

Comment: так разве смысл перегрузки в том, что бы обойти приватность?

Comment: @Maryna Said ,  просто я рассказал в каких случаях можно не перегружать оператор, но  о смысле перегрузки  Harry вам уже  очень хорошо рассказал...

Comment: @Maryna Said ,  ну вы же не можете  дать понять компилятору как выводится обьект вашего класса .  Вы даете команду художнику: нарисуйте мне  мою  комнату. А художник не знает какая она у вас, и что в ней есть.  А когда вы все это опишете, то только тогда он сможет нарисовать. И как компилятору знать как вы хотите увидеть вашу дату, в какой форме и что содержит класс?  Может вы хотите  чтоб при выводе даты выодилось просто " ok "  или еще что то....

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение) более мение становится яснее)

Comment: Фраза "смысл перегрузки в том, что бы *обойти* приватность" звучит как "смысл дверного ключа в том, чтобы леко *взломать* дверной замок"

Comment: @AnT ,  сравнили наилучшим образом...